# Changing value of element in 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

how do I change the value of 2d array without knowing its index?

Code:

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

for row in array:
    for col in row:
        if col == 2:
           ??????????? #this is what im looking for
```

Comment: please post a sample input and output

Comment: That's not a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

Try `enumerate()` in **both `for loops`**, which returns index position and value. Then change directly in your array.

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

for ir, row in enumerate(array):
    for ic, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == 2:
            array[ir][ic]= 99
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) function:

```
for row in array:
    for i,col in enumerate(row):
        if col == 2:  
            row[i]=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
for row in array:
    col[2] = #whatever you want to do
```

Comment: This will try replacing at index 2 not value 2.

Answer (score 1):

here is with numpy 2d array

```
import numpy as np
array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
array2d = np.array(array)
array2d

Out[1]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

# Here case if you know or column and/or row

array2d[:,2] = 0   # here is you 'i'..for example set column 2 to 0
array2d

Out[2]:
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [7, 8, 0]])

# Here case if you know condition, for example value '8' -> '88'

array2d[np.where(array2d ==8)] = 88
array2d

Out[3]:

array([[ 1,  2,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  0],
       [ 7, 88,  0]])
```

Comment: OP said he doesn't know the index ('i') to change the value.I believe he meant he want's to change when the value is a certain value, not change the whole column or row. But your answer made me doubt of that.

Comment: may be you right, so i extended my answer